# Good textbook for "second course" in discrete dynamics

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I am looking for a good textbook for a "second course" in discrete dynamics (research monographs also welcome). I enjoyed "A First Course In Discrete Dynamical Systems" by Richard Holmgren and am seeking a book on more advanced material.

Comment: The book that you mention is very bad, but does a fairly good job in the references indicating pointers (with extensive comments) for more advanced material. You might want to have a look at that part (starting with page 215) to check what would be in line with your taste. Be careful, one finds sentences such as: "I haven't seen these notes, but I understand that they are a fairly complete set of notes suitable for..." !!!

Comment: You might have a look at books by Robert Devaney, for example "An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems" (2003), ISBN 978-0813340852.